# Android Studio flutter show corrupted code in all classes

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, android-studio-arctic-fox

**Android studio Version :-
Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1**

All files show corrupted code check screenshot.

I have tried all the possible way to get it worked. This problem is currently in My flutter Code but native android project also have same problem.

- reinstalled android studio.
- deleted gradle caches.
- Invalidated/restarted project.

[image]

Comment: Check opening the files in a text editor

Comment: @TechnicalWorld files opening correctly in text editor (notepad )

Comment: I dont know of any other solution rather than deleting cache files, maybe you can copy paste the files manually

Comment: yes copy/pasting is last option i will do that if not found any other solution.

Comment: you have git. checkout from the last code if there is no newer code. if there is, check out local history option in android studio.

Comment: remove `caches` folder from here and try again`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3`

Comment: @NikunjParadva your answer is working for me. Very Thanks!

Comment: @NikunjParadva upvote this question aswell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple Step for your solution

- Exit `Android Studio`
- Delete `caches` folder from

  ```
  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
  ```
- Open `Android Studio` and your code has being Perfect

Comment: thank you so much. It's working perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is UTF-8 the encoding you want? Check in the lower right corner of android studio.